# SKSpriteNode - constant speed, and detect which SKSpriteNode does something

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have two questions:

1. How can I make an SKSpriteNode move at a constant speed and direction?
   I'm currently using `item.physicsBody?.velocity`, but I want just a constant speed, in the direction to the left.

```swift
let item = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 16))
item.position = CGPoint(x: 600, y: self.heights[random])
item.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width:32, height: 16))
addChild(item)
item.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -360, dy: 0)
item.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
```

2. I have the above code in `touchesBegan()`. I want to add some code to `update()`, to detect when one of these created SKSpriteNodes does a certain thing (e.g. reaches a specified x position), and then make a change to that SKSpriteNode (e.g. delete it). How do I do that, so that I get that particular SKSpriteNode?

Comment: Setting `velocity` is fine, and is the natural thing to do.  Note that by default sprites will slow down though.  Set `linearDamping` on the physics body to 0.0 if you don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just manually update your sprite's position. Define a speed in points per second, use a timer in `update()` to see how much time has passed since it was last called and with a bi of maths, work out its new position. I've done this and it works.
2. I'm not sure what the relevance of the `touchesBegan()` code is to this point (are you creating a sprite and setting it moving when you touch the screen?), but in general you could iterate over the array of child nodes in the scene using `enumerateChildNodes()`. When you have a node that matches your criteria (specific x position etc.), perform the action on the node.

Comment: If you want to give more detail, then I may be able to flesh out the answer a bit.